# Jquery for selecting all checkboxes not working

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, jquery-ui, frontend

Below is the jQuery I tried to use to select checkboxes when a button is clicked; however, when the button is clicked, the checkboxes aren't selected. Clicking the button doesn't do anything.

## Jquery for selecting all checkboxes

```
$("#selectAllPubTypes").click(function () {
    $(".pubbox").each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    });
});

#Html for button and checkbox group.i have a group of checkboxes here.

 <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light" name="selectAllPubs" id="pubs" style="background-color: #0C2340">All</a>

{% for value, text in form.PUBS %}
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class= "filled-in pubbox" name="pubcheckbox" value={{ text }}/>
        <span style="font-size: medium">{{ text }}</span>
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `$("#selectAllPubTypes")` selects the element with the ID `selectAllPubTypes` and you didn't post that. You need to post a [mcve]

Comment: You don't need `.each()`. `.prop()` will loop automatically over all the elements in the collection.

Comment: `#selectAllPubTypes` should just be `#pubs`.

Comment: @j08691 I think he *did* post a MCVE, and the bug is in it: the ID in the selector is different from the ID of the `All` link.

Comment: Working example https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/58932/

Answer (score 0):

There is no selectAllPubTypes ID in the HTML on your code, only a name that is selectAllPubs. The link / button has an ID called 'pubs'.

Also rather use .on("click")

```
$("#pubs").on('click', function() {
    $(".pubbox").each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    });
});


<a class="btn waves-effect waves-light" name="selectAllPubs" id="pubs" style="background-color: #0C2340">All</a>
{% for value, text in form.PUBS %}
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class= "filled-in pubbox" name="pubcheckbox" value={{ text }}/>
        <span style="font-size: medium">{{ text }}</span>
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you don’t have an id set as “selectAllPubTypes” on your html so doing this wouldn’t do anything. Try this

```
$(“#pubs”).click(function() {
   $(“.pubbox”).each(function() {
       $(this).prop(“checked”, true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider Toggling the All button. Consider the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#pubs").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).data("checked") == undefined) {
      $(this).data("checked", false);
    }
    if ($(this).data("checked")) {
      $(".pubs-wrapper .pubbox").prop("checked", false);
      $(this).data("checked", false);
    } else {
      $(".pubs-wrapper .pubbox").prop("checked", true);
      $(this).data("checked", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.pubs-wrapper span {
  display: block;
  font-size: medium;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn waves-effect waves-light" name="selectAllPubs" id="pubs" style="background-color: #0C2340">All</a>
<div class="pubs-wrapper">
  <!--
Template:
{% for value, text in form.PUBS %}
<span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in pubbox" name="pubcheckbox[]" id="pubchk-{{value}}" value="{{ text }}" />
  <label for="pubchk-{{value}}">{{ text }}</label>
</span>
{% endfor %}
-->
  <span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in pubbox" name="pubcheckbox[]" id="pubchk-1" value="Text 1" />
  <label for="pubchk-1">Text 1</label>
  </span>
  <span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in pubbox" name="pubcheckbox[]" id="pubchk-2" value="Text 3" />
  <label for="pubchk-2">Text 2</label>
  </span>
  <span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in pubbox" name="pubcheckbox[]" id="pubchk-3" value="Text 3" />
  <label for="pubchk-3">Text 3</label>
  </span>
  <span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in pubbox" name="pubcheckbox[]" id="pubchk-4" value="Text 4" />
  <label for="pubchk-4">Text 4</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

A user may want to select all or deselect all. This can be done in the same button is configured properly. Since a Button does not have a 'checked' attribute, we can make use of `.data()` to store this.

Also, `<label>` should be used with the `<input>`. Sort of weird to use it as a wrapper, not wrong, just not best practice for HTML.

Hope that helps.